# Displaying values from a Google spreadsheet on a WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, api, google-sheets

I have followed the tutorial on this website https://www.wp-tweaks.com/display-a-single-cell-from-google-sheets-wordpress/ which allows to dynamically display values from a Google spreadsheet on a WordPress page using a simple shortcode:

```
[get_sheet_value location="Cell Location"]
```

This solution worked seamlessly until a single page contained hundreds of those shortcodes (I basically need the whole content of the page to be editable via the spreadsheet). I started getting 100% Errors by API method (based on the Google Metrics) and the content was not displayed properly anymore. I realize that sending hundreds of read requests after each page load is not ideal and will inevitably affect the load performance and that Google imposes quota limits too. Is there a way to bypass this issue? For example by pulling the values from the Google spreadsheet only once a day. Unfortunately, I don't have much coding experience but I'm open to all solutions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mario, does it work if I only need to pull 2 cells from the googlesheet and display on the webpage? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could [publish the sheet to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965#embed_files) and embed it to your website:

1. In your sheet, go to **File** > **Publish to the web**
2. In the window that appears, click **Embed**.
3. Click **Publish**.
4. Copy the code in the text box and paste it into your site.
5. To show or hide parts of the spreadsheet, edit the HTML on your site.

It would look like this (click on Run code snippet):

```html
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR3UbHTtAkR8TGNtXU3o4hzkVVhSwhnckMp7tQVCl1Fds3AnU5WoUJZxTfJBZgcpBP0VqTJ9n_ptk6J/pubhtml?gid=1223818634&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading the entire spreadsheet as a JSON file and parse it within your code.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/cjn-google-sheets-as-json-endpoint/