# How to retrieve data from a googlesheet and display in a WordPress page?

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets

I'm building a WordPress page whose content has to be fetched from a googlesheet(Google excel) present on the googledrive. Is there a way to do this? Please share links to some documentation that I can reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check this post about [Displaying values from a Google spreadsheet on a WordPress page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488273/displaying-values-from-a-google-spreadsheet-on-a-wordpress-page) for more reference. Additionally, you can check [Display Google Sheets data in a WordPress site](https://sheetdb.io/use-cases/wordpress-with-google-sheets) as an alternative option.